# DBSCAN with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am creating a shiny application for DBSCAN of data consisting of geographical coordinates and use leaflet for showing these clusters on the map. My code is following.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('clustering of Data'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('eps', 'Please enter Eps value', 0.05),
      numericInput('minpts', 'Please enter MinPts value', 10),

    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput('plot2')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  pp <- reactive({

    dbscan(select(data, lat, lon), eps = input$eps, MinPts = input$minpts)
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({
    data

  })




  output$plot2 <- renderLeaflet(
    {

      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        setView(lng = -93.232256, lat = 44.973692,  zoom = 10) %>%
        addMarkers(lat = as.numeric(selectedData()$lat), 
                   lng = as.numeric(selectedData()$lon), color = color
        )

    }
  )

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I guess I can perform the DBSCAN and get clusters, but I am not able to show these clusters with different color on the map using leaflet. Please help

Comment: There's a bracket missing I guess. And sample `data`.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to color the clusters